# AutoMapper - ConstructProjectionUsing exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Using AutoMapper 5 and I was sure I was setting this up correctly, but I still get an EF exception:

```
'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'
```

StackTrace:

```
     at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
```

I've looked around saw that a fix was implemented for a bug with this method in 4.1.0+, but I've verified I'm using 5.0.0 and seeing similar behavior to the issue described here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/909

My data objects are simple:

**Character.cs:**

```
    public class Character : BaseModel
{
            public string Name {get;set;}
            public string Style { get; set; }
            public string MainImageUrl { get; set; }
            public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string ColorTheme { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**CharacterDto.cs:**

```
public class CharacterDto
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public CharacterDto(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

This is a Web Api and I'm configuring my mapping in Startup:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Character, CharacterDto>()
               .ConstructProjectionUsing(c => new CharacterDto(c.Name)));
```

I'm using EF 6 and returning an `IQueryable<CharacterDto>`:

```
[Route("characters")]
        public IQueryable<CharacterDto> GetCharacters()
        {
            return Db.Characters.ProjectTo<CharacterDto>();
        }
```

The Characters data is an `IDbSet<Character>` in my context.

I'm most likely missing something simple, but I'm unable to figure out what it is so far.

Comment: try to do it like that and give me a feed back: new CharacterDto() {Name =c.Name} // Add default constructor in your CharacterDto

Comment: @BassamAlugili CharacterDto.Name is readonly.  My understanding was that .ConstuctProjectionUsing allowed the usage of non-default constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the Automapper. The problem as you seen in your expression tree of the EF (missing stacktrace). EF doesn't support parametrized constructors in its expression tree. Maybe you do somewhere ToList to materialize the entities before you send it to the Automapper.

Comment: Alright fair enough. I think I was confused on whether or not automapper did something behind the scenes when executing the query prior to projecting that would allow me to bypass that EF limitation.